# Как удалить элемент div

Tags: html, jquery

Вроде бы делаю все правильно, но элемент не удаляется. Скрипт в самом конце.

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  alert("deleting...");
  $("div.chosen-search").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chosen-search"><input type="text" autocomplete="off"></div>
```

Comment: В показанном вами примере, если не забыть подключить jQuery, всё отлично удаляется

Comment: в том то и дело что должно, но не удаляет ) версия jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: @Denis Все работает, как я вижу на вашем примере.

Comment: Библиотека стоит ПЕРЕД кодом удаления. Библио - 3.3.1. Все нормально)

Comment: 2.1.4 не работает, а вот в 3.3.1 все ок. Может подскажите как удалить по значению в элементе <span>Day</span> найти и  полностью все удалить.

Comment: @Denis заменил в примере jQuery на 2.1.4 — всё равно всё работает. Пока вы не покажете неработающий пример, мы ничем не сможем вам помочь, ведь всё работает